# Why jq array returns length is greater than actual no of array items

Tags: arrays, bash, jq

i have a json file

```
{
  "file" : {
      "a" : 1,
      "b" : 2
    }
}
```

I am using `jq` to count number of keys file value have in this json object.

then using on bash

```
arr=($(cat jsonfile.json | jq '.file' | jq -r 'keys'))
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

here i get output 4 whereas there is only 2 keys a,b

Why is that so, and how do i get arr only have two elements `a` and `b`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why you get an array of 4 elements, look at the output of the sub-shell:

```
cat jsonfile.json | jq '.file' | jq -r 'keys'
```

This produces:

> ```
> [
>   "a",
>   "b"
> ]
> ```

Each line there becomes an element of the array -> 4 lines.

Try this instead:

```
jq -r '.file | keys | .[]' jsonfile.json
```

Output:

> ```
> a
> b
> ```

I also simplified your original expression. (Thanks @JeffMercado!)

Comment: `jq -r '.file | keys | .[]' jsonfile.json`

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado, that's great, updated my post (+ gave you credit)